# Certificate authority has changed for personal website - but I haven't changed anything?

Tags: tls, certificate-authority, openssl

I have the [**Certificate Patrol**](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/certificate-patrol/) addon ([website](http://patrol.psyced.org/)) installed in Firefox. While I mostly ignore the (far too many) warnings, today I saw that the **certificate authority** for my personal website has changed. This certificate is created by myself, self signed, and I didn't change anything for the past month or two.

I made a screenshot of the warning, and see two different SHA1 fingerprints. MD5 fingerprint changed from `-` to `undefined`. Organization name (O) changed as well from `unknown` to the name I gave it. I didn't click the "view certificate" buttons for both websites, and regret that now.

- What does this mean? Can I trust the certificate?
- How can I check that my certificate is still valid, created by me, not changed by someone or something else?
- Should I recreate it?

Comment: Is this a self signed cert?

Comment: Yes, it is self signed.

Comment: What does your website do, and what does it run on?  Some software packages I've seen automatically generate their own self-signed certs every once in awhile, though most come with a default cert that everyone with the package gets to start with, unfortunately.

Comment: The certificate is created by openssl, and is used by Tomcat 7 on a Ubuntu 14.04 server. I see that the validity period is only three months. I created it one month ago, in two months it's not valid anymore. I thought it would last longer, but apparently I didn't set that right.

Answer (score 3):

> What does this mean?

The certificate changed, as shown by the different SHA1 hashes. The MD5 hash field is no longer relevant as Firefox deprecated them.

> Can I trust the certificate?

No, if it changed without the admin (ie. your) intervention, you should be highly suspicious.

> How can I check that my certificate is still valid, created by me, not changed by someone or something else?

You should compare the new certificate with the copy/hash you kept locally when creating it. Because you wrote it down, right?

> Should I recreate it?

Not necessarily. If your certificate were compromised, it wouldn't have been detectable. OTOH, if you're not sure which certificate you created, generating a new one would be appropiate.

.

Although this shows that there was a man-in-the-middle attack on you/your website, probably the new (forged) certificate was generated by a captive portal or even your router, and not someone targetting you at the network level.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The key was created one month ago, and is two more months valid. I may have entered a wrong date, but normally I would use a certificate that is valid for at least a year. I'm going to recreate it, and then write the hash down, and be more alert about it.